# Unable to get buttons currentTitle from UIStoryBoardSegue

Tags: swift, uikit

```
override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
    if segue.identifier == "Choose Theme" {
        if let themeName = (sender as? UIButton)?.currentTitle {
            if let theme = themes[themeName] {
                if let cvc = segue.destination as? ConcentrationViewController {
                    cvc.theme = theme
                }
            } else {
                print("something went wrong")
            }
        } else {
            print("couldnt get current title")
        }
    }
}
```

There is the code. I'm trying to get senders current title. I tried debugging and it prints "couldn't get current title", the value that I'm getting is nil.

What am I doing wrong?

Thanks in advance

Comment: post `performSegue` call

Comment: Code isn't showing for you ?

Comment: So debug it. Log sender. If it’s not nil, unwrap it and log `type(of:sender)` to see what kind of object it is.

Comment: @isifip i see the code , i need you to add more context to it ? as what action you do that fires that segue method ?

Comment: You've shown `prepare(for:sender:)`. This is called after there have been a `performSegue(withIdentifier:sender:)`, either by code, or by Storyboard setting. That's what was asking Sh_Khan. Which one is it? Could you print `sender`?

Comment: Is this being triggered from a segue you attached to a button, when you tap that button? That is the only case in which sender would be a button.)

Comment: @DuncanC Yes, that's exactly how it is. I click button which triggers segue to the other view. I'm getting view but since I'm unable to get buttons current title I can not populate with correct data. I have current title connected to the array which must trigger different results for different buttons.

Comment: Changing buttons style to default fixed it somehow... Thanks Everyone!

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using currentTitle, you might want to try titleLabel?.text.  It seems to be more reliable.  I got your program to work (tested in Xcode) using this change.